# Handling Development and Production Versions of AWS Lambda

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, aws-lambda

I have created an AWS-Lambda function, that sends FCM push notification to customers and then inserts a record (through stored procedure) to MSSql database. It is working well, but I have to maintain 2 projects, one function for development purpose with local database credentials, and another function for production with live server's database credentials.

Note: I have stored the database credentials and other config files in a c# class within the project.

Is there any way in vs17 to deploy the deploy the function just by changing any settings in the "Publish to AWS Lambda" dialog, so that I dont have to maintain two independent projects?

Thanks,

Comment: You could use precompilation directives with `#if DEBUG` and `#if RELEASE`

Answer (score 2):

Sensitive and RuntimeEnvironment specific data can be read from Environment Variables and AWS Lambda has a support for it.

You can easily achieve it [serverless framework](https://serverless.com/) with config files and variables ([example](https://forum.serverless.com/t/development-staging-and-prod-environments/2451/2)).

After all it comes down to simple commands:

$ serverless deploy --stage Prod //uses specified config file for setting environmental variables

$ serverless deploy --stage Dev

What it does is it sets Environment Variables at deploy time depending on the cli option. So in your code you read ConnectionString from Environmental variables.

You can achieve this as well without the serverless framework.
For this, you have to define Environment Variable yourself either at deploy time or hard coded on Lambda Function in AWS Console (which you know is Prod or Dev or...).
Then you have to read it in your application directly like `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ConnectionString")`

Instead reading directly what I choose to do is I bootstrap my function with something like using Microsoft Extensions.

```
    IConfigurationRoot configuration = GetConfiguration();
    // Read values from appsettings{Env}.json file.
    var connString = configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStringField"))

    private static IConfigurationRoot GetConfiguration()
    {
        var environmentName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
        Console.WriteLine("EnvironmentName: " + environmentName);
        return new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/AppSettings")
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.json", optional: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environmentName}.json", optional: true)
            .Build();
    }
```

So I keep separate files for each stage (Prod, Dev...) in the same project. Sensitive data is read during the runtime from the appropriate json file.
You can look more into how to do a better DependecyInjection and Configuration at .net core. [Example1](http://michaco.net/blog/EnvironmentVariablesAndConfigurationInASPNETCoreApps),  [Example2](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/setting-and-reading-values-from-app-settings-json-in-net-core/)